# How to change screen brightness in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have qr page in xamarin forms, and what i want is when the qr is shows up the screen brightness will be brighter, and i cant find solutions for that. i found some code in internet but it return with some error code message

EDITED :
I deleted the source code because its look like make some people confused, the code that i tried is for xamarin android and thats why it didnt work for me (I thought the xamarin.android and xamarin.forms code is almost same thats why i copy the code and paste it in xamarin forms and got some error message). And now my Real question is How to Change the screen brightness via xamarin Forms can we do that ?  if yes how any link that can i try thanks

Comment: the error means that .Attributes isn't a static property of the Window class. You can only use it on a specific instance of the Window class.

Comment: ok now forget about the error, my question is how to change screen brightness in xamarin forms ? Is that a right code for do that ? if yes i will try to fix the error

Comment: I would frown upon apps that turn up/down my global brightness settings for the app that I set so that my screen is readable and does not hurt my eyes... also my phone autoadjust brightness sometimes depending on sensordata / day of time. The whole Idea is kindof against UI design rules for disabilities - screenreaders voices do not get brighter that way.

Comment: @PatrickArtner well i just try to achieve what my client ask, and my client ask me to add this feature. but yeah you right this idea is not very effective, but still i must try to add that its what my client ask

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang You don't always _have_ to do exactly what the client says, especially if it doesn't make sense. You have the option of persuading them, based on your technical expertise, that what they are asking for is a bad idea. If you mention that it makes the solution cheaper and/or quicker, since you don't have to spend time to research and implement the feature, that might help to persuade them. Usually clients will thank you if you stop them doing something silly or unnecessary.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your advice im learning so much here, im still green in this job and lack of experience. im still very young (18 years old) and im just junior engineering so i dont have guts to do that.  but yeah if i'm already senior engineering maybe i will do that

Comment: Well in that case you could try to influence your own boss or senior engineer rather than the client directly. They in turn may have more influence than others. Hopefully your company does not have the kind of culture which makes people afraid to make suggestions - good creative ideas can come from anyone, and management always has the right to say "thanks, but no thanks" at the end of the day. But they should at least listen to your proposal and maybe be happy that you show some initiative

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms is *not* a platform abstraction, but a UI abstraction. Hence there is no access to system services like the screen brightness. Neither did I find a NuGet to achieve this, hence you'll have to implement platform specific classes to adjust the screen brightness and resolve via [`DependencyService`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/).

Implement the interface in your PCL

```
public interface IBrightnessService
{
    void SetBrightness(float factor);
}
```

and use that interface operations using `DependencyService` from your common project to your platform specific implementation

```
var brightnessService = DependencyService.Get<IBrightnessService>();
brightnessService.SetBrightness(.2);
```

For a very good compact example of how to use DependencyService see this page

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction

### Android

Your error message

> An Object is required for the non static field, method , or property 'Windows.Attribute'

means that you are trying to access a type as if it was an object. You need a context in which there is a `Window:Window` object, this would be the case in your `MainActivity` for instance.

When you are in another context you'll need to obtain an instance of `Window` somehow. Pre 2.5 this was possible with

```
var window = ((Activity)Forms.Context).Window;
```

This still works, but is deprecated. Anyway, you could use the [*CurrentActivity* plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.CurrentActivity/) and get the `Window` with

```
var window = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.Window;
```

([source](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/307585/#Comment_307585))

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof (AndroidBrightnessService))]

public class AndroidBrightnessService : IBrightnessService
{
    public void SetBrightness(float brightness)
    {
        var window = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.Window;
        var attributesWindow = new WindowManagerLayoutParams();

        attributesWindow.CopyFrom (window.Attributes);
        attributesWindow.ScreenBrightness = brightness;

        window.Attributes = attributesWindow;
    }
}
```

### iOS

Use `UIScreen.MainScreen.Brightness` to adjust the brightness.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using UIKit;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof (iOSBrightnessService))]

public class iOSBrightnessService : IBrightnessService
{
    public void SetBrightness(float brightness)
    {
        UIScreen.MainScreen.Brightness = brightness;
    }
}
```

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang Edited my answer.

Comment: I have question how to chage it back to default brightness of the phone , so i want to override back buton pressed and put the method there so when the page is closed the brightness is back to normal (to the setting of the phone) any idea how to implement it ? thanks

Comment: @TheodorusAgumGumilang You've probably figured it out by now, but for future readers, the way I restored the old setting was by adding a static variable to hold it in each of the platform classes, `private static float? _lastBrightness = null;`, then in the `SetBrightness` method, I save the old value into it right before the line where we set it `= brightness;`. Finally, I added `void ResetBrightness()` to the interface and implemented the method in both like this: `if ( _lastBrightness.HasValue ) { SetBrightness( _lastBrightness.Value ); }`

Comment: @RichardMarskell-Drackir, I want to change brightness in my app after 10 minutes of last user's any activity in an app. (Just like a computer screen server). I have achieved this in iOS(By overriding UIApplication class) but I don't know from where I can monitor all the touch, tap, event of a user. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: @PaulKertscher, Can you help me in my above query ?

Answer (score 0):

Android:

```
    public void SetBrightness(float brightness)
    {
        Window window = (MainActivity.Instance as Activity).Window;
        var attributesWindow = new WindowManagerLayoutParams();

        attributesWindow.CopyFrom(window.Attributes);
        attributesWindow.ScreenBrightness = brightness;

        window.Attributes = attributesWindow;
    }
```