# How can I change brightness inside of my app and that it will change on a real display device

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm developing an app that connects to a device. I would like to change brightness through the app, so that it will be change on the device. Can someone point me in the right direction of how to access the device and change brightness?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change screen brightness in xamarin forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47769514/how-to-change-screen-brightness-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: Thanks for responses but no I wasn't clear enough I guess. I have an app in Xamarin that connects to some other device that our company is developing. And I want to change through the app the brightness on the other device. Imagine your app connecting to Garmin and changing brightness.

Comment: do you have some sort of link to the device (such as Bluetooth?) and does the device expose some sort of interface for changing brightness? It would definitely be specific to the device and how you're connecting to it.

Comment: In android, you can put following code in your `MainActivity.cs`. `WindowManagerLayoutParams layoutParams =Window.Attributes;
            layoutParams.ScreenBrightness = Float.ParseFloat("ScreenBrightness value, I set it to 0-1");
            Window.Attributes=layoutParams;` Then use messageCenter to execute it, when you need to change the ScreenBrightness.